# import pandas as pd NameError: name 'null' not defined on jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, python-3.9

Hello I'm currently taking a data analyst bootcamp course on Udemy and I'm using jupyter notebook with python version 3.9. I'm currently learning how to use pandas library I installed it on my computer and I even upgraded it to version 1.1.4. When I run

```
import pandas as pd
```

and execute the cell I get this error message

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\pandas.py in <module>
     25   {
     26    "cell_type": "code",
---> 27    "execution_count": null,
     28    "metadata": {},
     29    "outputs": [],

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

I tried restarting the kernel and also restart and clear output but it's still giving me this error.

Comment: looks like you have named one of your local programs as pandas.py. so when you import pandas, it is importing your file instead of the pandas library

Comment: Your right i named one of my files as pandas.py, i deleted that file so now it works thank you! Also i even used import numpy as np right before import pandas as pd and it worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a local file named `pandas.py`. Delete the local file pandas.py and rerun it. That will resolve.

The import statement is trying to import your local file instead of the pandas library

Answer (score 0):

You may have a local file named `pandas.py`. Delete the local file `pandas.py` and rerun it. That will solve that.

The import statement is importing your local file instead of the `pandas` library.